# Rails-like console for PHP?

Tags: php, console, debugging

Every so often, things work in my local PHP development environment, while in my test environment on my server, things do not. It's a nightmare to debug this. If I had a console like Rails provides, debugging would be much much simpler.

Is there anything like the Rails console but for PHP?

I should mention that I am using a home-brewn PHP application.

Comment: The Symfony Frameworks has a nice console interface. It is extremely useful.

Comment: PHP is a language. Rails is a framework.

Comment: @webbiedave The Ruby language itself has a console: 'irb'. The Rails console simply builds on top of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a basic interactive shell available by running `php -a`. It doesn't have the bells and whistles of a framework-based console though.

More info can be found in the docs: http://docs.php.net/commandline.interactive

Comment: I think this is the closest thing to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Like webbiedave mentioned php is a language and Rails is a framework of Ruby. However, you could insert "break-points" into your php Script - and either execute from the browser - or if you have php-cli installed execute the script from CLI (Which isn't exactly the same as the browser, but may also provide more helpful information).

A few other tips - dump the environment settings for each machine, devel and production (with a simple script that has

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And compare the differences - this may help highlight why certain portions are failing between environments.

Lastly you can run php interactively with php -a much like you can with irb and ruby though it may not be as helpful in this situation.

Comment: The problem I experienced was actually due to bad data in the test database, so looking at the system configuration won't always help.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own application console with the `-d` and `-a` flags for the php-cli. It would be something like:

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=init.php -a
```

Your `init.php` would be whatever file bootstraps your application code. E.g. for WordPress, this would be wp-load.php.

http://franklinstrube.com/blog/rails-like-console-php/

Comment: This worked for me and it was surprisingly good.  I could boot up wordpress and make calls to an active record type of data structure I was developing.

Answer (score 0):

`php -a` is not very useful.

I suggest you write a small script like below and place it in **/usr/bin**:

```
import readline
from subprocess import call

pre_lines = """
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        call(["php", "--version"])
        print
        while True:
            user_input = raw_input('php> ')
            if user_input.strip() == "":
                continue
            elif user_input.find("=")>=0 and user_input.find("==")==-1:
                pre_lines += user_input + ";\n"
            elif user_input.find(";")>=0:
                call(["php", "-r", "%s\n%s" % (pre_lines, user_input)])
            else:
                call(["php", "-r", "%s\nvar_export(%s);" % (pre_lines, user_input)])
                print
    except EOFError:
        print "Bye"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Bye"
    except OSError:
        print "You either don't have PHP installed, or the PHP binary is not in PATH"
```

With above, you'll have readline support and check values of equations easily.